# Where can I find the historic stock prices of delisted stocks?

Tags: stocks, stock-exchanges

I need to find a chart of historic prices for Exide Technologies' old stock symbol: `XIDE`. This was the symbol of the company until its bankruptcy, after which its symbol changed to `EXIDEQ`.

Where can I find the stock prices of `XIDE`, and other delisted stocks, for free on the internet?

Comment: Exide Technologies still trades today as an OTC stock under the symbol XIDEQ albeit at a low price ($0.073 on 20 Apr 2015).  We have the full history available in our US historical database back to its initial listing on 21 Apr 2004.    Some sources only report to two decimal places so watch for rounding issues.